# Find the 1st occurence of elements in a list of strings, based on first character in the string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I am new to python. I am trying to get the 1st number in a list of strings that are numbers in a series, that start with a common number.

ex:

```
x = ['512','345','321','345','674','132','231','145','214','576']
```

my expected output:

```
result = ['512','345','674','132','231']
```

i.e say for example in all numbers starting with 1 in list, I should get the 1st number likewise for all other numbers.

I could use for loop twice to get it. but i want to know is there any better way of doing it.

NOTE: the list is a list of strings which are numbers given was just an example.

Comment: Can you explain why your expected output is what you expect? I don't understand what algorithm you're trying to create. Showing what code you have so far, and indicating either whether it works or not (and if not, how it fails) would also be helpful.

Comment: Your English is little poor here, not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: I am trying to print the 1st number of each sublist . say for example the list contains numbers between 1 to 1000 all numbers less than 100 is one sublist and numbers lessthan 200 is a sublist. I could break list into sublists and do this. but i want to do it with one list only.

Comment: a list of strings is actually a list of lists of characters, so that's a different problem to solve, unless you convert the numbers to strings

Comment: please find the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator function to do this. In the function you just iterate your initial list and for each element check if there is another element that starts with the same character already exists in a `set` of string. If no match found, just `yield` that element.

```
>>> def get_num(lst):
...     found = set()
...     for element in lst:
...         if not any(item.startswith(element[0]) for item in found):
...             found.add(element)
...             yield element
... 
>>> x = ['512','345','321','345','674','132','231','145','214','576']
>>> list(get_num(x))
['512', '345', '674', '132', '231']
```

Comment: Worked perfect (Y)